# FTP Downloads corrupted file in Delphi using IdFTP

Tags: delphi, ftp

I am using `IdFTP` to download an `.exe` or `.zip` file from a FTP server. The file is downloaded and comes to my computer from FTP, the problem is that the `.exe` **gets corrupted** during the transfer and I cannot open it inside my computer.

Here is the code.

```
  IdFTP1.Connect;
  IdFTP1.Get(EdtRemoteFile.Text,EdtDirectory.Text + '\' + EdtRemoteFile.Text, True, true);
```

Answer (score 6):

The FTP protocol operates in ASCII (text) mode by default. In this mode, line breaks are normalized during transmission, which will corrupt binary files (and it can also potentially corrupt non-ASCII text files too, like UTF-8). So, you need to switch to IMAGE (binary) mode when transferring non-textual files, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., IdFTPCommon; 

IdFTP1.Connect;
IdFTP1.TransferType := ftBinary; // <-- ADD THIS
IdFTP1.Get(EdtRemoteFile.Text,EdtDirectory.Text + '\' + EdtRemoteFile.Text, True, true);
```

Comment: UTF-8 can't get corrupted. Only legacy encodings such as Big5 can be.

Comment: @Olivier UTF-8 *can* get corrupted, if the implementation of ASCII mode transfer is not 8-bit safe by either party.  `TIdFTP`'s implementation is (it always transfers data in an 8-bit safe way, regardless of the mode), but there is no guarantee that the server's implementation is 8-bit safe.  Transferring in IMAGE mode, on the other hand, gives that guarantee for both parties.

Answer (score 0):

A `.txt` file would work, the problem is with `.exe` and `.zip` files. You need to add this line to your code:

```
uses
  ..., IdFTPCommon;

IdFTP1.TransferType := ftBinary;
```

Don't forget to import `IdFTPCommon` otherwise you can't use `ftBinary`.

Comment: And all other non-textual files, I suppose (PNG, WMV, DOCX, DLL, ...).